# CSS: Fix row height

Tags: css, html-table, row

I'm having this markup:

```
<style>
    table
    {
        border:1px solid black;
        width:400px;
        height:300px;
        border-collapse:collapse;
    }
    table tbody
    {
        border:1px solid red;
    }
    table td
    {
        background:yellow;
        padding:10px;
        border-bottom:1px solid green;
        height:20px;
    }
</style>


<table>
<tbody>
    <tr><td>test</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

What I need is that the rows won't stretch in height.
Is there a way to have a fixed row height?

Comment: What do you want to do with content that's taller than the fixed row height?

Comment: Use min-height, and hope the users don't have IE6.

Comment: @tad: min-height does the exact opposite of what he asked for. Also note that max-height does not work correctly under certain circumstances under IE8 unless you are using compatibility mode: http://edskes.net/ie8overflowandexpandingboxbugs.htm

Comment: table > tbody:after { clear: both; content: ''}
Try this as well. ^ Worked for me.

Answer (score 35):

HTML Table row heights will typically change proportionally to the table height, if the table height is larger than the height of your rows.  Since the table is forcing the height of your rows, you can remove the table height to resolve the issue.  If this is not acceptable, you can also give the rows explicit height, and add a third row that will *auto* size to the remaining table height.

Another option in CSS2 is the Max-Height Property, although it may lead to strange behavior in a table.http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-height.asp

.

Comment: best. answer.  hard setting the table height was causing all of my problems, removing it made for awesome.

Comment: +1 for "you can also give the rows explicit height, and add a third row that will auto size to the remaining table height."

Comment: Max-Height Property didn't solve the problem for me

Comment: This answer gave me the idea of adding a blank row at the bottom with height: 100%

Answer (score 24):

Simply add `style="line-height:0"` to each cell. This works in IE because it sets the line-height of both existant and non-existant text to about 19px and that forces the cells to expand vertically in most versions of IE. Regardless of whether or not you have text this needs to be done for IE to correctly display rows less than 20px high.

Comment: This just solved my problem in Chrome 30 too, I was trying to make an <img> take up the full size of the table cell it was in with no gaps

Comment: line-height 0 seems to make text run together if it tries to wrap:
http://jsfiddle.net/6wXd8/

Answer (score 8):

You can also try this, if this is what you need:

```
<style type="text/css">
   ....
   table td div {height:20px;overflow-y:hidden;}
   table td.col1 div {width:100px;}
   table td.col2 div {width:300px;}
</style>


<table>
<tbody>
    <tr><td class="col1"><div>test</div></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="col2"><div>test</div></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5):

I haven't tried it but if you put a div in your table cell set so that it will have scrollbars if needed, then you could insert in there, with a fixed height on the div and it should keep your table row to a fixed height.

Answer (score 0):

```css
    
    table tbody
    {
        border:1px solid red;
    }
    table td
    {
        background:yellow;
        
        border-bottom:1px solid green;
        
        
    }
    .tr0{
        line-height:0;
     }
     .tr0 td{
        background:red;
     }
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr><td>test</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test</td></tr>    
    <tr class="tr0"><td></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This method works very well for having rows with fixed height, and stop the table layout shifting.
You will have to add a `<tr class="auto-height"></tr>` that will fill up the rest of the table for you, so your rows won't have to expand and can save their fixed height.

```html
<table class="table" >
  <tr class="fixed-height" >
    foo1
  </tr>
  <tr class="fixed-height" >
    foo2
  </tr>
  <tr class="fixed-height" >
    foo3
  </tr>
  <tr class="auto-height" > // responsible for filling up the table
  </tr>
</table>
```

```css
.table {
  height: 80vh;
}

.fixed-height {
  height: 50px; /*fixed height for table rows */ 
}

.auto-height {
  height: calc(100% - 100px); /* Remaining height assigned to a non visible row */
}
```