# Resizable <div> inside <td>. How to not affect <td> height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, resizable, jquery-resizable

I have resizable `div` (JQuery UI Resizable) inside `td` cell. `td` has css property `height=18px`.
But when I resizing this `div`, table cell also resized.

So is there possibility to resize `div` and not affect `td` height?

**SOLVED!**

Comment: please post what you have tried out

Comment: Hi there. When inserting fragments of code, enclose them in backticks to format them correctly.

Comment: You mean you want to have the div overflow the table cell if the div is bigger than the cell?

Comment: Since the `div` is a child of your `td` cell your `td` cell will automatically resize when the dimensions of its child are bigger than its own. Unless you want an overflow on your `td` cell.

Comment: Could you not just use the `containment: $('td_selector')` property that's shipped with the jQuery UI Resizable plugin?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806371/css-fix-row-height